# Showing multi row in one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing a page where I have to show all the jobs of an employee with a work number and the total of each type of hours in each work

I can display it, but, my problem is

when the employer works on the same job twice it displays the same job twice too

I have this:

```
JOB      | H1     | H2      | H3      | H4      | H5      | H6

O-2019-1 |   2.00 |    2.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    1.50        
O-2019-1 |   1.50 |    0.50 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    1.50 |    0.00
```

I want this:

```
JOB      | H1    | H2       | H3      | H4      | H5      | H6

O-2019-1 |  3.50 |     2.50 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    1.50 |    1.50
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php 
    $stmt = $link -> prepare("SELECT * FROM rostosativos_funcionarios WHERE contribuinte = ?;");
    $stmt -> bind_param('s',
            $_GET['id']);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $resultado = $stmt -> get_result();
    $r = $resultado -> fetch_assoc();
    $id_funcionario = $r['id_empregado'];
    $stmt -> close();


    $sql = $link -> prepare("SELECT * FROM rostosativos_trabalhos WHERE id_funcionario = ?;");
    $sql -> bind_param('s',
            $id_funcionario);
    $sql -> execute();
    $resultado = $sql -> get_result();
    $sql -> close();

?>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<?php while($r = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<section class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Obra: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['id_obra']; ?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora 1: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['hora_a']; ?>h" class="form-control" disabled>
                    </div>

                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora 2: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['hora_b']; ?>h" class="form-control" disabled>
                    </div>

                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora 3: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['hora_c']; ?>h" class="form-control" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use group by for the first column and sum group function on the hours

```
Select job, sum(h1) h1, sum(h2) h2, ....
From ....
Where ....
Group by job
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was already complaining the code because I was overthinking ... I completely forget the  " Group by"... thank you @Saad Ahmad